# Drawing background lines in an EditText that uses a custom font or typeface

Tags: android, fonts, android-edittext, typeface

I am trying to subclass EditText to create a new textbox with horizonal lines (as found on lined paper). Here is my basic code:

```
public class LinedEditText extends EditText {

    // the paint we will use to draw the lines
    private Paint dashedLinePaint;

    // a reusable rect object
    private Rect reuseableRect;

    public LinedEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public LinedEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public LinedEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the paint object.
     */
    private void init() {

        // instantiate the rect
        reuseableRect = new Rect();

        // instantiate the paint
        dashedLinePaint = new Paint();
        dashedLinePaint.setARGB(200, 0, 0, 0);
        dashedLinePaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        dashedLinePaint.setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[]{4, 6}, 0));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        Log.e("LINE_HEIGHT", "Line height for typeface is " + getLineHeight());

        // get the height of the view
        int height = getHeight();

        // get the height of each line
        int lineHeight = getLineHeight();

        // the number of lines equals the height divided by the line height
        int numberOfLines = height / lineHeight;

        // if there are more lines than what appear on screen
        if (getLineCount() > numberOfLines) {

            // set the number of lines to the line count
            numberOfLines = getLineCount();
        }

        // get the rectangle instance
        Rect r = reuseableRect;

        // get the baseline for the first line
        int baseline = getLineBounds(0, r);

        // for each line
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++) {

            // draw the line
            canvas.drawLine(
                    r.left,                 // left
                    baseline,               // top
                    r.right,                // right
                    baseline,               // bottom
                    dashedLinePaint);       // paint instance

            // get the baseline for the next line
            baseline += getLineHeight();
        }

        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

...this works perfectly when I use the default system font:

> 01-20 15:31:08.172    3966-3966/com... E/LINE_HEIGHT: Line height for typeface is 63

[image: with system font]

But as soon as I call linedEditTextBox.setTypeface(typeface), it is drawn this way:

> 01-20 15:33:58.938    4064-4064/com... E/LINE_HEIGHT: Line height for typeface is 83

[image: with custom font]

Does anyone know what is happening here? Should I be overriding setTypeface in my subclass, and doing some type of calculation to determine the new line height? I am stumped, any input is appreciated.

Here are some other StackOverflow questions I've looked at that seemed to be related:
[EditText draw lines wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11529597/edittext-draw-lines-wrong)
[Drawing multiple lines in edittext e.g. notepad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972388/drawing-multiple-lines-in-edittext-e-g-notepad?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. For some reason I had to subtract one from the line height returned from getLineHeight(), no idea why. It works now, here is the complete code for the class:

```
public class LinedEditText extends EditText {

    // the vertical offset scaling factor (10% of the height of the text)
    private static final float VERTICAL_OFFSET_SCALING_FACTOR = 0.1f;

    // the dashed line scale factors
    private static final float DASHED_LINE_ON_SCALE_FACTOR = 0.008f;
    private static final float DASHED_LINE_OFF_SCALE_FACTOR = 0.0125f;

    // the paint we will use to draw the lines
    private Paint dashedLinePaint;

    // a reusable rect object
    private Rect reuseableRect;

    public LinedEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public LinedEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public LinedEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {

        // instantiate the rect
        reuseableRect = new Rect();

        // instantiate the paint
        dashedLinePaint = new Paint();
        dashedLinePaint.setARGB(200, 0, 0, 0);
        dashedLinePaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        // set the path effect based on the view width
        dashedLinePaint.setPathEffect(
                new DashPathEffect(
                        new float[]{
                                getWidth() * DASHED_LINE_ON_SCALE_FACTOR,
                                getWidth() * DASHED_LINE_OFF_SCALE_FACTOR},
                        0));

        // get the height of the view
        int height = getHeight();

        // get the height of each line (not subtracting one from the line height makes lines uneven)
        int lineHeight = getLineHeight() - 1;

        // set the vertical offset basef off of the view width
        int verticalOffset = (int) (lineHeight * VERTICAL_OFFSET_SCALING_FACTOR);

        // the number of lines equals the height divided by the line height
        int numberOfLines = height / lineHeight;

        // if there are more lines than what appear on screen
        if (getLineCount() > numberOfLines) {

            // set the number of lines to the line count
            numberOfLines = getLineCount();
        }

        // get the baseline for the first line
        int baseline = getLineBounds(0, reuseableRect);

        // for each line
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++) {

            // draw the line
            canvas.drawLine(
                    reuseableRect.left,             // left
                    baseline + verticalOffset,      // top
                    reuseableRect.right,            // right
                    baseline + verticalOffset,      // bottom
                    dashedLinePaint);               // paint instance

            // get the baseline for the next line
            baseline += lineHeight;
        }

        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Looking correct now:

[image: correct with new font]

Comment: Have you tried this with other sizes? This doesn't seem like a valid solution. To answer your question, yes there is a measureText method you'll be able to find in the docs of you do want a more robust solution

Comment: I tried to calculate the size of the text using measureText but it returns only the width of the rendered text, not the height. I also tried Paint.getTextBounds(), which populates a Rect object, but even when including ascending and descending characters with test string  "ABC...abc...123..." I still got 83px for the height. For some reason, with this font, subtracting one from the height works, even on the ten thousandth line everything still lines up. You are right, my answer seems like a hard coded hack, and I'm still looking for a programmatic solution, but this works.